# Get the differences in minutes of two dates in a virtual column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried most of the things i found scouring the web for this problem and none of them really paid off so i have to ask here:
How do i get the difference of 2 dates in a vistual column?
I tried this way:

```
    CREATE TABLE RENTALS(
    RENTID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    PICKUPDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    LEAVEDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TIMEINMIN NUMBER AS (PICKUPDATE-LEAVEDATE)*24*60,
    CUSTOMERID NUMBER(13) NOT NULL,
    VINNUMBER VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    PRICEPERMIN DECIMAL(1,2) NOT NULL,
    REMARKS VARCHAR2(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(RENTID)
);
```

on insert i get this error:

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

when i try:

```
    CREATE TABLE RENTALS(
    RENTID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    PICKUPDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    LEAVEDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TIMEINMIN NUMBER AS ROUND((PICKUPDATE-LEAVEDATE)*24*60),
    CUSTOMERID NUMBER(13) NOT NULL,
    VINNUMBER VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    PRICEPERMIN DECIMAL(1,2) NOT NULL,
    REMARKS VARCHAR2(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(RENTID)
);
```

On create i get:

> ORA-02000: missing ( keyword

As pointed out, i am adding my insert statement here:

```
INSERT INTO RENTALS(RENTID,PICKUPDATE,LEAVEDATE,CUSTOMERID,VINNUMBER,PRICEPERMIN,REMARKS) VALUES(1,SYSDATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE),1234567891011,'AAZZDDAF1234',1,'NEW SCRATCH');
```

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking for free help. Thanks.

Comment: Problem is in `PRICEPERMIN DECIMAL(1,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're blaming the wrong column(s).

```
SQL> create table rentals
  2    (pickupdate date,
  3     leavedate date,
  4     timeinmin number as ((pickupdate - leavedate) * 24 * 60)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into rentals (pickupdate, leavedate) values (sysdate, sysdate - 1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from rentals;

PICKUPDATE LEAVEDATE   TIMEINMIN
---------- ---------- ----------
06/20/2020 06/19/2020       1440

SQL>
```

Which means that virtual column is OK (why wouldn't it be? Difference of two dates is number of days which multiplied by 24 and 60 is a relatively small number).

Therefore, check **other columns** you're inserting, especially the ones whose size is constrained.

It would be easier to assist if you posted `INSERT` statement; as you did not, you'll have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Thank you, i did add my insert statement now. Should i point out that i am using oracle academy express?

Comment: You're welcome. Oracle Academy Express? Doesn't seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is right but you are not closing in paranthesis. I think adding it should work.

```
CREATE TABLE RENTALS(
RENTID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
PICKUPDATE DATE NOT NULL,
LEAVEDATE DATE NOT NULL,
TIMEINMIN NUMBER as  (round((PICKUPDATE-LEAVEDATE)*24*60)),
CUSTOMERID NUMBER(13) NOT NULL,
VINNUMBER VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
PRICEPERMIN DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
REMARKS VARCHAR2(50),
PRIMARY KEY(RENTID));
```

Comment: thank you. it finally worked! But still, on insert i get this error ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

my insert looks like this:
INSERT INTO RENTALS(RENTID,PICKUPDATE,LEAVEDATE,CUSTOMERID,VINNUMBER,PRICEPERMIN,REMARKS) VALUES(1,SYSDATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE),1234567890,'AAZZDDAF1234',1,'NEW SCRATCH');

Comment: It is problem with pricepermin column where your scale is lower than precision value. I have edited it.